# Filling data into an hidden div with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div class="panel">
  <form id="form" method="post" ng-submit="submit">
    <select ng-controller="CountryController" ng-model="model.country" ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in model.countries">
      <option value="">Country</option>
    </select>
   </form>
 </div>

div.panel {
  display: none;      
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

The panel is initially hidden and I have a button to show / hide it.

Because the panel is initially hidden the select is not filled.

If I remove the display:none from the panel then the select is filled.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You wish to have the select not filled in either case? Or have the select filled in either case?

Comment: I want to have it always filled

Comment: What is providing information to you that it is in fact NOT filled in when it is hidden?

Comment: It should still be filled if it's hidden. Check the inspector in the browser developer tools

Comment: got it, just wondering how you were checkout out its state. I'll check it out.

Comment: Yes, in fact it is filled. The problem is when using this directive: https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/angular-selectize.js/tree/master ... In this case when it is hidden the select is not filled.

Comment: I am using this directive because I am using http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ to style my select.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to jsFiddle

[Your code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/egec0uc2/6/)

In the jsFiddle example the select is filled in whether it is hidden or not. Just dig down into the DOM and you will see the values. I was going to recommend using ng-show so I included it in the jsFiddle, but it's grayed out. I thought that perhaps it was due to the nested controller, but in the jsFiddle it works. Maybe playing around with this jsFiddle will help. Can you provide more code or a copy of your actual DOM and what it is showing?

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-show="showMe" class="panel">
      <form id="form" method="post" ng-submit="submit">
        <select ng-model="model.country" ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in countries">
      <option value="">Country</option>
    </select>
   </form>
 </div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
// on load set default of ng-show
// $scope.showMe = false;
  $scope.countries = [{Id:0, Name: 'USA'},{Id:1, Name: 'China'}];

// When you are ready to show the select, just run a function that sets showMe to true.
});

app.controller('CountryController', function($scope){
  $scope.countries = [{Id:0, Name: 'USA'},{Id:1, Name: 'China'}];
});
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a working plunker with the Angularjs-selectize working. However, the behavior is the same as you stated. Looking through the selectize.js it creates it's own templates and probably adds and removes these as needed. This is why I am trying to get more information about what you really need to happen. Let's play with this and see what you need. Or perhaps you can get what you need from this plunker?

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tfH2oX?p=preview)

Comment: Please, see my last comment. I am also using https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/angular-selectize.js/tree/master directive and http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ and this seems to make this not work when the div is hidden. Any idea why?

Comment: I see. Is there ANY parent DOM element that the select is embedded in that is using a ng-if?

Comment: ng-if will not load with the initial DOM load, but only after its condition is true; which means some code may over look it. I'll play with these items you mentioned in the fiddle and get back to you.

Comment: No, I don't think so ... at least not in my code ... I am just starting with angular and there are somethings that i might not be aware

Comment: Is the select present when u inspect it? Just without options, except the initial Country option correct?

Comment: Yes, the select is present ... And it has the initial Country but not other options. You are right. Do you know what is going on? Sorry, for the delay ... Overnight here.

Comment: More info: why do you need the option data loaded in the DOM when the element is hidden? If its for CSS do you only need the select element present?

Comment: I do not need it ... I only need it when showing the select list. I am also having problems using selectize with validation ... Now I am trying this: https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize ... But I would prefer to use the select tag then a selectize tag

Comment: But again, I am also not sure that this will work. I am just starting now.